# How to run my react program in my ios device

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, simulation

How to run my react program in my ios device?

I have a React Native code and i want to test it in my Iphone.

I do step by step this [way](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device) from Document of React Native.

But when i want to run my program in my device this error will be shown:

[image]

ps: my code is correctly run on Xcode Simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my issue is solved by this command:

```
react-native run-ios --device
```